# Finding a point on a line

Tags: math, opengl, linear-algebra

I know the start and end points on a line segment.  For this example say that the line segment has a distance of 5.  Now I want to know the point that has a distance of three away from the end point.  Any idea how to do this with math?

Start Point (0,0)
End Point (0,5)

Point I want to find (0,2)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If your points are `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)`, and you want to find the point `(x3, y3)` that is `n` units away from point 2:

```
d = sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2) #distance
r = n / d #segment ratio

x3 = r * x2 + (1 - r) * x1 #find point that divides the segment
y3 = r * y2 + (1 - r) * y1 #into the ratio (1-r):r
```

Comment: +1 - After hours and hours of trying to get this working I finally thought, "Hey, why not check SO." 30 seconds later I have a fully working solution.  For my purposes I swapped the x's and y's in the x3,y3 calculation so that it would represent the distance from the starting point.